# Opportunity Product scheduling

Tags: opp-lineitemschedule

I want to create the schedule for all the Products of an Opportunity in one step.

What is the best solution available ??

I can think of creating the button on product related list on Opportunity and call the VF page

Answer (score 1):

Set the default revenue or quantity scheduling for the product and you should be good to go.

Comment: hello, I have a strange requirement : to correct opportunities in sytem : and as part of this correction via dataload the Opportunity schedules get wiped out. I want to reload the data for these pre-existing opportunities schedule in system, but cant find the table name in Dataloader..Is it not allowed? or how shall i go about this,as certain reports are based on this?

Comment: @user10727 that's a great question, can you ask it as a separate question? you'll be able to get a lot better answers that way (since people don't tend to focus on question that already have an answer), and you'll benefit the community, since other users can find your question and see the answer (something they can't do if you just put it in this comment)

Comment: thanks for the reply, found the table name which is required from Dataloader ,so dint post my query again.